# Can ios UIAutomation run each test case from beginning?

Tags: javascript, ios, automation, ui-automation

I wrote some `UIAutomation` test cases to test my app, but I didn't find anyway to run each case from beginning. When a test case failed would cause other cases failed as well. Is there any way let `UIAutomation` run each script from app beginning. I means when a test failed app can quit test and continue run second test from beginning.

I also used `tunneup.js` to write my scripts. In a `test.js` file the structure of scripts are:

```
test("test1", function () {
  some code.
});
test("test2", function () {
  some code.
});
```

Currently when test1 failed, would let test2 failed as well, I want when test1 failed app can quit and start again to run test2 case.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd suggest is to keep your test cases independent from one another so you don't get cascading failures. Nonetheless, you can setup a base state so your automation can "recover" and continue with the remaining test cases. For example, if you have a main view, start your test cases by making sure you're at the main view before continuing.

Comment: but some case may failed and cannot go back to main view. So the next case cannot continue. So how to handle this?
currently my way is, go back to first screen after case run, and next case would run start first screen.

but this cannot handle the situation that case failed at the middle.

Comment: My problem is when a test case failures how to let case go back to the first screen. Then next case will continue.

Comment: That's why your "base state" should include different ways to get back to your home view in case of any failure. I'm pretty sure you can go back to the main view from any of your other views, correct? Just write a function for this base state and call it at the beginning of every test case.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to quote few points, that will help you in building good test scripts.

1.Try to maintain a different scripts for different test cases that will help you in solving the problem of not reaching the next test case.

2.Try to maintain some reusable scripts, like going to home from any point or moving to a particular screen when needed and import them in the scripts, which will help you in reaching to test case easily in each of the different script.

I am answering this question knowing that you have knowledge of writing and importing scripts. If no , please do comment with you query.